# Download a file with phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, download

I need to download a file, but I Don't his name.
I try to download without specifying his name.
Folow my code

```
$("#sincronizar").click( function(){
            var localFileName = "ico/recebe/";
            window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
                fileSystem.root.getFile(localFileName, {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(fileEntry) {
                    var localPath = fileEntry.fullPath;
                    var url = "http://192.168.250.100:5000/envia_arquivo/?username=dlemes&password=101112";
                    var onSucess = function(entry) {
                            alert("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
                            //extractFile();

                        };
                    var onError = function(error) {
                            alert("Erro ao buscar fonte de dados: " + error.source);
                            alert("Código do erro: " + error.code);
                        };
                    var ft = new FileTransfer();
                    ft.download(url,localPath, onSucess, onError);  
                });
            });      
        });
```